# Testing Symfony controllers in isolation

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony 2 application with the FOSRestBundle. Following standard design guidelines, I'm breaking away from the framework as soon as I can. My controller methods look as follows:

```
public function getFooBarAction() {
    $service = Factory::newWithConnection( $this->get( 'database_connection' ) )->newFooBarService();
    return $this->handleView( $this->view( $service->doStuff() ) );
}
```

`Factory` is the top level factory of my app. My integration tests all construct a in memory sqlite database, install my applications tables into it and create an instance of `Factory` with it. This is encapsulated by

```
$testFactory = TestEnvironment::newInstance()->getFactory();
```

This means that all my tests using a database only have the data available that the test explicitly adds, and that the tests remain fully isolated from each other.

Now I want to add some system tests to make sure the parameter handling of my API endpoints works correctly. I can create test classes that derive from `WebTestCase` and then get a `$client` via `static::createClient()`. That however then uses the database the Symfony DI mechanism returns. I can change that to an in memory sqlite one via `config_test.yml`, though that does not give me actual isolation of the tests.

Can I do something like `getNewSymfonyApplication( $myNewConnection )->createClient()`?

Comment: Following standard design guidelines means following the framework and at least, not using singleton instances and static methods...

Comment: No singleton is used. Static methods are generally bad except when they are constructors (notice how constructors are an inherently static concept). That's not related to my question though.